# In excel, how do i hide duplicate value of Column A & B (where AB=BA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

[image: example]

In my data there are 3 columns.

Where I want to show unique route only.

### Data

| Location-1 | Location-2 | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | BBB | 10 |
| BBB | CCC | 20 |
| CCC | DDD | 30 |
| BBB | AAA | 10 |
| DDD | CCC | 30 |

### Target is.

| Location-1 | Location-2 | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | BBB | 10 |
| BBB | CCC | 20 |
| CCC | DDD | 30 |

Thank you!

I want to show unique values only.

**Note: I am using Excel-2013**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A3:B5,
     b, REDUCE(A2:B2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(c,d,VSTACK(c,SORT(INDEX(a,d,),,,1)))),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(b,C2:C5)))
```

---

**Test Case One:**

[image]

---

**Test Case Two:**

[image]

---

Since OP has updated that their version of **`Excel is 2013`**, therefore here is a solution, which works from **`Excel 2010+`** onwards.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$C$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,
 (ROW($A$3:$A$7)-ROW($A$3)+1)/(IFERROR(IF($A$3:$A$7&"|"&$B$3:$B$7<>"",
 MATCH($A$3:$A$7&"|"&$B$3:$B$7,$B$3:$B$7&"|"&$A$3:$A$7,0)),
 ROW($A$3:$A$7)-ROW($A$3)+1)>=ROW($A$3:$A$7)-ROW($A$3)+1),
 ROWS(E$3:E3)),MATCH(E$2,$A$2:$C$2,0)),"")
```

---

**Notes:** One needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode for the approach which supports **`Excel 2010`** onwards as well as needs to fill down & fill right accordingly, also ensure to change the cell references and ranges as per your suit.

---

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Specific Duplicates

[image]

```
=LET(data,A2:C6,sCol,1,eCol,2,dlm,"@",
    start,CHOOSECOLS(data,sCol),
    end,CHOOSECOLS(data,eCol),
    ds,start&dlm&end,
    de,end&dlm&start,
    s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(ds)),
FILTER(data,IFNA(XMATCH(ds,de),s)>=s))
```

Answer (score 0):

In column <kbd>D</kbd> (starting in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>) enter the following formula:

```
=CONCAT(SORT(A2:B2,,,TRUE))
```

[image]

Then select the entire cell range, go in the ribbon to `Data` -> `Data Tools` -> `Remove duplicates` and select column <kbd>D</kbd> only.